# Distance properties of the permutations of a set of points in a Euclidean space

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, permutations, combinatorial-optimization

We are given a set of $n$ distinct points $S=\{\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n\}$ in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, where the distance between two points $\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j\in S$ is denoted by $d(i,j)$ for any $i,j\in[n]$, and $\max_{i,j\in [n]}d(i,j)=1$. Let $\mathcal{\Pi}$ be the set of all functions $\pi$ mapping each index of a point of $S$ to a distinct integer in $[n]$, namely a permutation on the indices of the points of $S$. We also define

$$R(\pi):=\sum_{\substack{(i,j,k)\in[n]: \\\pi(i)<\pi(j)<\pi(k)}} \left(1-d(i,j)\right)~,$$

$$\pi^*:=\arg\max_{\pi\in\mathcal{\Pi}} R(\pi)~.$$

---

**Question:** Can we prove the following conjecture? Does the answer depend on the number of dimensions of the Euclidean space?

*For any pair of elements $\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j\in S$ such that $\pi^*(i)<\pi^*(j)$, the average value of $R(\pi)$ over all $\pi\in\mathcal{\Pi}$ such that $\pi(i)<\pi(j)$, is greater than or equal to the average value of $R(\pi')$ over all $\pi'\in\mathcal{\Pi}$ such that $\pi'(i)>\pi'(j)$.*

Comment: It is an interesting question. I did not think carefully about it. Did you run some numerical calculations for instance?

Comment: Thank you. Not specifically for this problem. I run some numerical experiments for this related question (which is even more important for my research now): https://mathoverflow.net/q/365472/115803

Comment: Bu the way, about the problem of this webpage, I hope that two average values of the question cannot be arbitrarily close to each other (when $n\gg 1$, and even when $n\to\infty$).

Comment: I guess in the sum for $R(\pi)$ should be figured $k$.

Comment: Also functions $\pi$ mapping each point of $S$ to a distinct integer in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ are bijective maps from $S$ to $\{1,\dots,n\}$, whereas permutations of the elements of $S$ are bijective maps from $S$ to $S$.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I removed the sentence about permutations (but I would not modify the title, because the two concepts are tightly related and it can quickly provide information about the topics of this problem).

Comment: I could also define $\pi$ as a bijection between the indices of the vectors.